# How can I define a specific colour for the textures from the ExampleData?

Tags: graphics, color, textures

Suppose I have the given Mathematica code,

```
Graphics3D[{Texture[ExampleData[{"ColorTexture", "GloriesPattern"}]], Sphere[{0, 0, 0}]}, Boxed -> False]
```

which gives me a nice coloured texture around the unit sphere as below:

[image: sphere-color-texture]

But, when I try using this code:

```
Graphics3D[{Texture[ExampleData[{"Texture", "Grass"}]], Green, Sphere[{0, 0, 0}]}, Boxed -> False]
```

it gives me a black&white texture as below:

[image: sphere-texture]

Is there a way with which I can even provide specific colors to such kind of example texture data?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The image you get from `ExampleData[{"Texture", "Grass"}]` is a grayscale image. The colors you see are due to the default ["5-point" lighting](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Lighting.html#25236). If you set `Lighting -> "Neutral"`, you get:

```
Graphics3D[{Texture[ExampleData[{"Texture", "Grass"}]], 
  Sphere[{0, 0, 0}]}, Boxed -> False, Lighting -> "Neutral"]
```

[image]

If you want to convert this grayscale image to a colored one, you can use [`Colorize`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Colorize.html) with whatever [`ColorFunction`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ColorFunction.html) you want:

```
Graphics3D[{Texture[Colorize[ExampleData[{"Texture", "Grass"}], 
 ColorFunction -> "AvocadoColors"]], 
  Sphere[{0, 0, 0}]}, Boxed -> False, Lighting-> "Neutral"]
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

```
img = ExampleData[{"Texture", "Grass"}];
colors = DominantColors[img]
img = ColorReplace[img, Thread[colors -> {Green, Pink}]];
Graphics3D[{Texture[img], Green, Sphere[{0, 0, 0}]}, Boxed -> False]
```

[image]

Comment: Why are there some small white or light greyish patches in the output texture?

Answer (score 2):

You could also use [`AmbientLight`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/AmbientLight.html) as well.

```
Graphics3D[{AmbientLight[Darker@Green], 
  Texture[ExampleData[{"Texture", "Grass"}]], Green, 
  Sphere[{0, 0, 0}]}, Boxed -> False]
```

And from there choose what `Lighting` you like.